# Service to send GPS coordinates to server

Tags: android, service, timer, gps

I'm new in android and I am trying to send gps coordinates to a web server. I already get the GPS coord and request updates of them every X seconds.

What I want is to send those coords to a web server using a Service and running the service in different time intervals (user will decide how ofter he wants to update his position).

I have already searched and I want to do it the more efficient possible, that's why I think using a Service would be the best approach.

I'm having trouble knowing where to start the service and how to make it run in time intervals, also if I should use AsyncTask inside the service to POST the coords to the webserver.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 3 people gave you answer below answers is working for you? or not? atleast reply your feedback its your courtesy brother.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the answers and go coding after that. I was going to reply when I got something functional. For now I already got the service running with location listener and starting every X sec with Alarm Manager. I will now try sending data with asyncTask. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an **AlarmManager** that starts a service every X sec.

The **service** should include a class that implements a **location listener**.

Refer this tutorial **[link](http://ukgupta.blogspot.in/2011/09/acquiring-gps-location-fix.html#comment-form)** that will helps you to know about the **service** and **time** **intervals**.

And you simply get the **coordinates** within an **activity** from the **service** and send it to the server using **Async task**.

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks!, I want to use something like this because I think this is the best approach to take, but still having some difficulties. By now I already have the service running without problems. (I'll post my code when already having asynctask running too)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using AlarmManager.
I used onLocationChanged() from LocationManager

**LocServ.java**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by BrijD on 14-12-22.
 */
public class LocServ extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private static String url_insert_location = "http://172.20.10.4/testing/insert.php";
    public static String LOG = "Log";

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 0 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 ; // 1 second

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    public LocServ(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public LocServ(){
        super();
        mContext = LocServ.this;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service started");
        Log.i("asd", "This is sparta");

        new SendToServer().execute(Double.toString(getLocation().getLongitude()),Double.toString(getLocation().getLatitude()));

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service destroyed");
    }

    class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... la ) {

            try {

                Log.i("string" , la[0]);
                String longi = la[0];
                String lati = la[1];

                // Building Parameters
                Log.d("value", lati);
                Log.d("value", longi);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longi));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lati));

                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_location, "POST", params);
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("error", e.toString());
            }

            return "call";
        }



    }


    public Location getLocation () {
             try {
                 locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                         .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                 // getting GPS status
                 isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                         .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                 // getting network status
                 isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                         .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                 if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                     // no network provider is enabled
                 } else {
                     this.canGetLocation = true;
                     if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                      //updates will be send according to these arguments
                         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                 LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                 MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                 MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                         Log.d("Network", "Network");
                         if (locationManager != null) {
                             location = locationManager
                                     .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                             if (location != null) {
                                 latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                 longitude = location.getLongitude();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                     if (isGPSEnabled) {
                         if (location == null) {
                             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                     LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                     MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                     MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                             Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                             if (locationManager != null) {
                                 location = locationManager
                                         .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                 if (location != null) {
                                     latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                     longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return location;
         }




    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//this will be called every second
        new SendToServer().execute(Double.toString(getLocation().getLongitude()),Double.toString(getLocation().getLatitude()));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below service related code to achieve your requirement
where in `onTick()` method you can write your code to send data(GPS cordinate) from your device to web server even you can write your GPS related code here in this service(getting gps cordinate )

TimerService.java

```
package com.android.yourpackagename;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class TimerService extends Service {

    // variables
    MyCounter timer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        timer = new MyCounter(30 * 60 * 1000, 1000);//counter of 30minutes and tick interval is //1 second(i.e.1000) you can increase its limit whatever you want as per your requirement
        super.onCreate();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //timer finished 30 minutes
         stopSelf()//to stop service after counter stop 
        }


        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //timer clock tick event after each 1 second 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
        // call start servce here for lifetime running of service
        // startService(new Intent(this, TimerService.class));

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

register your TimerService.java into manifest using below code

```
<service
        android:name="com.android.yourpackagename.TimerService"
        android:process=":TimerService" >
    </service>
```

start service from your activity using startService() method like

```
   startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerService.class));
```

stop service using stopService() method like

```
 stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            TimerService.class));
```

Hope this will help you cause it worked for me with same requirement :)

Comment: I tried this when I saw your answer, but I'm not sure if this would be as efficient as running an Alarm for the service. However, it helped me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use the volley library instead of asynchronous task

this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-vs-asynctask-better-approach/) explain the difference 
and this's a method that can help you understand how to use it :

```
 public static void postLatAndLongAndId(final Context context,String id,String imei,String latitude,String longitude) {
            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_login";
            // progress bar showing 
            pDialog.setMessage("votre reservation est en cours de traitement ...");
           showDialog();
           //create jsonObject to post it  
           final JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
            try {
                body.put("id_client",id );
                body.put("imei",imei);
                body.put("lat",latitude);
                body.put("long",longitude);
                body.put("type","b2c");  

             //   Log.e(TAG, "jsonObj body: " + body );  

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_POSTING_USER_COORDINATES, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                         //   Log.e(TAG, "WebS Response: " + response.toString());

                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                             //   Log.e(TAG, "affichage de jobj =: " + jObj );
                                String status = jObj.getString("status");

                   //    Log.e(TAG, "status = ok ?? " + status.equals("OK") );
                                // Check for error node in json
                                if (status.equals("OK")){
                         //data send successfully 
                                    hideDialog(); 

                                } else {
                                    // Error . Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                               //     Log.e(TAG, "webS Error: "+errorMsg);
                                    Toast.makeText(context,
                                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    hideDialog(); 
                                    alert.showAlertDialog(context, "Désolé", " Une erreur est survenue, veuillez essayer ultérieurement",true);
                                }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // JSON error
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                         //  Log.e(TAG, "webS Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            hideDialog(); 
                         alert.showAlertDialog(context, "Désolé", " Une erreur est survenue, veuillez essayer ultérieurement",true);
                        }
                    }) {


                 @Override
                 public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    // Log.e(TAG, "j'ai executé la methode getBody!! ");  
                     return body.toString().getBytes();
                 }
                @Override 
                public String getBodyContentType()
                {

                    return "application/json";
                }      

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

        }
```

hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Alaram service or timer is good approach to perform time dependant tasks, but its best to use handler with post dalyed of your choice to perform any task you want, if you are using alarm manager than you are requesting OS to perform your task after some time, same with timer but for handlers you are using/managing in your own code